# Select an option from a select object when scraping data from a dynamic webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm doing some web-scraping and I'd like to know how to select data from a dropdown box and scrape it. Here's the page: https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/ExchRateByCurrency.asp

As you can see, it's a dynamic web-page and there's the option to show how many entries you'd like.

[image: Snippet of web page showing entries dropdown box which allows selection of number of entries to show]

What I want to do is select the maximum (100), and then scrape the data from the table afterwards. Any ideas how I can go about this? Here's some code you can build on:

```
Firefox = Firefox()
Firefox.get(source["Exchange Rates by Currency"])

sleep(30)

html = Firefox.page_source
html = bs(html,"html.parser")
table = html.find("table",id="exTable")

select_item = html.find("select")
```

It'll take you right to the table and select items respectively.

Comment: Do you want to scrap the data? or its just you want to know how to play with dropdown using Selenium ?

Comment: I want to display it and then scrape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below approach using python - **[requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io)** simple, straightforward, reliable, fast and less code is required when it comes to requests. I have fetched the API URL from website itself after inspecting the network section of google chrome browser.

What exactly below script is doing:

1. First it will take the API URL and do a GET request.
2. After getting the data script will parse the JSON data using json.loads library.
3. Finally it will iterate all over the list of exchange rate by currency list and print them for ex:- Buying rate, Central rate, Currency, Selling rate , Rate date.

   ```
   import json
   import requests
   from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
   requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

   def scrap_cbn_data():

   URL = 'https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/outputExchangeRateJSN.asp?_=1605068636834' #API URL

   response = requests.get(URL,verify=False) # GET request
   json_result = json.loads(response.text) #Parse JSON data using json.loads
   extracted_data = json_result['data'] #extracted data

   for item in extracted_data: #iterate over the list of exchange rate by currency
       print('-' * 100)
       print('Buying Rate : ', item['buyingrate'])
       print('Central Rate : ', item['centralrate'])
       print('Currency : ', item['currency'])
       print('Rate Date : ', item['ratedate'])
       print('Selling Rate : ', item['sellingrate'])
       print('-' * 100)

   scrap_cbn_data()
   ```